# Oracle SQL Developer debug error - "The file-based source <Package Name> is not present in the database."

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer to try to debug a package-level function. After I compile both the header and the body of the package for debug, I find my function in the source (which was loaded from the DB to begin with), and the debug dialog gives me the message,

"The file-based source [Package Name] is not present in the database. 
Was it compiled?"

Like I said, I had literally just compiled the code, and I didn't notice any errors.

**EDIT:** I had commented out the function definition in the header file, so the function wasn't public.

Comment: When you say you didn't notice any errors are you sure there are none?  What does `select object_type, status from user_objects where object_name = 'PP_POST_PKG';` return?

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to format it well, but it says both the package and package body are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had commented out the function definition in the header file, which effectively made it a private function, so it wouldn't let me call it from SQL Developer.

I uncommented the function definition, making it a public function, and it worked.